# How to pipe stream to reply in hapi.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, hapi.js

Im looking for the parllel method in hapi

```
// Express + Request exmaple
function(req, res){
  request('http://example.com/image.png').pipe(res);
}
```

How to pipe a response in hapi ?

```
server.route({
method:  "*",
path:    "/api/results/{date}",
handler: (request, reply) => {


    //????reply(?);



}
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you can. Does request support the streams2 api? From the hapi docs: `Stream object (Note - any Stream object must be compatible with the "streams2" API and not be in objectMode)` http://hapijs.com/api#reply-interface

Comment: I've done it with the aws-sdk module: `reply(s3.getObject(params).createReadStream());`

Comment: server.route({
 method:  "*",
 path:    "/api/results/{date}",
 handler: (req, reply) => {
  var fs = require('fs');
  var fileStream = fs.createWriteStream('./doron');
  request('http://google.com/doodle.png').pipe(fileStream); 
  reply(fileStream); 
 }
});  this throwes the follwoing exception Debug: internal, implementation, error
    Error: Stream must have a streams2 readable interface

Comment: That's what I saw which is why I said that I don't think the request module supports streams2. You could try https://www.npmjs.com/package/wreck but I'm not sure if that'll work either.

Comment: ok i'll look into wreck , my problem now is that request module doesnt support streams2 . My opinion , is that hapi should support , and encourage people to use streams. after all my investigation i found there is not enough docs , about streams support in hapi .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From another question/answer:

```
function (request, reply) {

    Request('http://example.com/image.png')
    .on('response', function (response) {
        reply(response);
     });
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31222563/2573244

Comment: These doesnt , uses the power in streams . streams are simple .on('data' , ... listeners wich emits events on every data event . the asnwer you posted are basicly listening to the end event

Comment: @doronaviguy You are wrong. The response is a stream, and the event is emitted immediately after the headers have been processed.

Comment: @Gil Thanks, you are right . 'response' event is [http.Incomming] (http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_incomingmessage) which is a stream object 
Quote from  http module Docs http.Incomming
**It implements the Readable Stream interface**

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to forward an upstream response, you can just use a proxy handler via the h2o2 plugin:

```
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/upstream/file',
    handler: {
        proxy: {
            uri: 'http://example.com/image.png'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: that methods handle stream response ?