# How do I stream data to browsers with Hapi?

Tags: node.js, request, streaming, hapi.js

I'm trying to use streams to send data to the browser with Hapi, but can't figure our how. Specifically I am using the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module. According to the docs the `reply` object accepts a stream so I have tried:

```
reply(request.get('https://google.com'));
```

The throws an error. In the docs it says the stream object must be compatible with [streams2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/streams2), so then I tried:

```
reply(streams2(request.get('https://google.com')));
```

Now that does not throw a server side error, but in the browser the request never loads (using chrome).

I then tried this:

```
var stream = request.get('https://google.com');
stream.on('data', data => console.log(data));
reply(streams2(stream));
```

And in the console data *was* outputted, so I know the stream is not the issue, but rather Hapi. How can I get streaming in Hapi to work?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try using [`Readable.wrap`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_wrap_stream):

```
var Readable = require('stream').Readable;
...
function (request, reply) {

  var s = Request('http://www.google.com');
  reply(new Readable().wrap(s));
}
```

Tested using Node 0.10.x and hapi 8.x.x. In my code example `Request` is the node-request module and `request` is the incoming hapi request object.

**UPDATE**

Another possible solution would be to listen for the ['response' event](https://github.com/request/request#streaming) from `Request` and then `reply` with the `http.IncomingMessage` which is a proper read stream.

```
function (request, reply) {

     Request('http://www.google.com')
     .on('response', function (response) {
        reply(response);
     });
}
```

This requires fewer steps and also allows the developer to attach user defined properties to the stream before transmission. This can be useful in setting status codes other than 200.

Comment: there is a verstion of that answer for hapi 17.9.0?

Comment: I find the problem with the compression method `gzip` in the response. so now I research how to by pass it by `flush` method or disable

Answer (score 5):

### 2020

**I found it !!** the problem was the `gzip` compression

to disable it just for `event-stream` you need provide the next config to `Happi` server

```
const server = Hapi.server({
  port: 3000, 
  ...
  mime:{
    override:{
      'text/event-stream':{
        compressible: false
      }
    }
  }
});
```

in the handler I use `axios` because it support the new stream 2 protocol

```
async function handler(req, h) {
    const response = await axios({
        url: `http://some/url`,
        headers: req.headers,
        responseType: 'stream'
    });

    return response.data.on('data',function (chunk) {
        console.log(chunk.toString());
    })

    /* Another option with h2o2, not fully checked */
    // return h.proxy({
    //     passThrough:true,
    //     localStatePassThrough:true,
    //     uri:`http://some/url`
    // });
};
```