# Stream an HTML response using Hapi

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I'm trying to figure out how to stream an HTML response using Hapi. I have a test code snippet below. This returns the HTTP headers immediately but nothing written to the stream is sent to the browser until `stream.end()` is called. Hapi claims to support streams so I assume I'm just not setting up the stream properly.

```js
'use strict';

const Hapi = require('hapi');
const Stream = require("stream");

const server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({ port: 3000, host: 'localhost' });

server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/',
  handler: (request, reply) => {
    const stream = new Stream.PassThrough();
    stream.write('<html><head><script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.3.1/dist/react.min.js"></script>');
    reply(null, stream).type('text/html').code(200);

    setTimeout(() => {
      stream.write('</head><body>hello</body></html>');
      stream.end();
    }, 2000);
  }
});

server.start((err) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
});
```

The use case here is to be able to send the `<head>` of the HTML so the browser can start downloading resources while the rest of the content is still being generated on the server.

Comment: Most likely you're not seeing data streamed because it's being buffered in the gzip encoder. AFAIK hapi doesn't provide an API to flush this on demand.

Comment: FYI I submitted this suggestion on hapi's issues: https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/issues/3599

Comment: Thanks, you were right about gzip encoder being the issue. I found if I add one line of code to hapi to expose the compressor I'm able to get it to work by calling `flush()`. I'll comment on the issue you raised.

Comment: I find answer for that here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59467467/1919821