# convert object stream to readable stream hapi

Tags: hapi.js, mongojs

I am creating REST api with hapi and mongojs.  I need to output large number of JSONs as API response. I am using following code. But getting error “Error: Stream must have a streams2 readable interface”.

```
handler: function(request, reply) {
        reply(db.collection.find().pipe(JSONStream.stringify()));}
```

How do I convert mongojs object stream to readable stream?

I tried following code as well

```
var outputStream =  db.collection.find().pipe(JSONStream.stringify());
reply(outputStream.pipe(new Readable().wrap(outputStream)));
```

but it doesn't show any data in output.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31210950/how-do-i-stream-data-to-browsers-with-hapi